# Invalid column name, not ID, Entityframework, although column exist

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I have a strange problem. I'm using `Entity Framework` in my application.
At a simple loop through database items I keep getting `Invalid column name error`

```
 var list = ggisContext.TreeElements.Where(x => x.PlotDescription != null && x.VolumeElementActualUa > 0).ToList();
  foreach(var item in list)
  {...}
```

The list is filled with the elements, the error starts when I reach the `foreach`.
The `TreeElements` has a virtual `navigation property` to `PlotDescription` model, which contains a `ProposedWorks2` property. Even this property is present in PlotDescription model, it is present in database, I get the following error:
[image]

This is the `TreeElement` and the `PlotDescription` `class`:

```
public class TreeElement
{
    [Key]
    [DatabaseGeneratedAttribute(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("PlotDescription")]

    public int? PlotDescriptionId { get; set; }
    public int? TreeId { get; set; }
    public int? RegenerationModeId { get; set; }
    public int? OriginId { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("PlotDescriptionId")]
    public virtual PlotDescription PlotDescription { get; set; }
    .......
}

public class PlotDescription
{
    [Key]
    [DatabaseGeneratedAttribute(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int? ProductionUnitId { get; set; }
    public string Plot { get; set; }
    public string SubPlot { get; set; }
    public string ProposedWorks1 { get; set; }
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Computed)]
    public string ProposedWorks2 { get; set; }
     .....
}
```

Can you please advise how to resolve this problem?

Comment: `ProposedWorks2` is this a computed column which does not exists on the table?

Comment: It exist on the table, this is why is so strange, and I don't know what can I try in order to resolve this.

Comment: You can add logging (`context.Database.Log = Console.Write; ` - [see this article](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn469464(v=vs.113).aspx)) to EF, so you will see what query framework is trying to execute. Try to compare this request with database structure

Comment: I think computed columns get a bit "weird" in Linq queries. I would first change ProposedWorks2 to a private set.  Then, if it works for your project, you could add [NotMapped] attribute to ProposedWorks2 and do the calculation for the value of the column yourself in C# rather than depend on the DB.